# Default code page for each language version of Windows

Tags: windows, unicode, character-encoding, codepages

Where can I find information about which code page is default for each language version of Windows? I.e the *"ANSI"* code page for each language version.

I've found the [Code Pages Supported by Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964654.aspx), but I cannot find the defaults for each language.

I'm guessing that for instance, Windows-1253 (Greek) is the default when installing the Greek language version. But what about the other code pages? And is Windows-1253 the default for any other language version?

Answer (score 5):

Following [Mihai Nita's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7685385/758345), I extracted the following data. For brevity, I summarized some languages with many variants into xx-*.

These are [ISO 639-1 language codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes). Wikipedia also has more info on [the code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page).

> #### Windows-1250 / Latin-2 (Central European)
>
> bs, bs-Latn, bs-Latn-BA, cs, cs-CZ, hr, hr-BA, hr-HR, hu, hu-HU, hu-HU_technl, pl, pl-PL, ro, ro-MD, ro-RO, sk, sk-SK, sl, sl-SI, sq, sq-AL, sq-MK, sq-XK, sr, sr-Latn, sr-Latn-BA, sr-Latn-ME, sr-Latn-RS, sr-Latn-XK, tk, tk-TM
>
> #### Windows-1251 (Cyrillic)
>
> az-Cyrl, az-Cyrl-AZ, ba, ba-RU, be, be-BY, bg, bg-BG, bs-Cyrl, bs-Cyrl-BA, ky, ky-KG, mk, mk-MK, mn, mn-Cyrl, mn-MN, ru, ru-BY, ru-KG, ru-KZ, ru-MD, ru-RU, ru-UA, sah, sah-RU, sr-Cyrl, sr-Cyrl-BA, sr-Cyrl-ME, sr-Cyrl-RS, sr-Cyrl-XK, tg, tg-Cyrl, tg-Cyrl-TJ, tt, tt-RU, uk, uk-UA, uz-Cyrl, uz-Cyrl-UZ
>
> #### Windows-1252 / Latin-1 (Western European)
>
> af, af-NA, af-ZA, arn, arn-CL, bin, bin-NG, br, br-FR, ca, ca-AD, ca-ES, ca-es-*, ca-FR, ca-IT, co, co-FR, cy, cy-GB, da, da-DK, da-GL, de, de-*, dsb, dsb-DE, en, en-*, es, es-*, eu, eu-ES, ff, ff-*, fi, fi-*, fil, fil-PH, fo, fo-FO, fr, fr-*, fy, fy-NL, ga, ga-IE, gd, gd-GB, gl, gl-ES, gn, gn-PY, gsw, gsw-CH, gsw-FR, gsw-LI, ha, ha-*, haw, haw-US, hsb, hsb-DE, ibb, ibb-NG, id, id-ID, ig, ig-NG, is, is-IS, it, it-CH, it-IT, it-SM, iu, iu-Latn, iu-Latn-CA, jv, jv-Java, jv-Java-ID, jv-Latn, jv-Latn-ID, kl, kl-GL, kr, kr-Latn, kr-Latn-NG, la, la-001, lb, lb-LU, moh, moh-CA, ms, ms-BN, ms-MY, ms-SG, nb, nb-NO, nb-SJ, nl, nl-*, nn, nn-NO, no, nso, nso-ZA, oc, oc-FR, pap, pap-029, pt, pt-*, quc, quc-Latn, quc-Latn-GT, quz, quz-BO, quz-EC, quz-PE, rm, rm-CH, rw, rw-RW, se, se-FI, se-NO, se-SE, sma, sma-NO, sma-SE, smj, smj-NO, smj-SE, smn, smn-FI, sms, sms-FI, sv, sv-AX, sv-FI, sv-SE, sw, sw-CD, sw-KE, sw-TZ, sw-UG, tn, tn-BW, tn-ZA, tzm, tzm-Latn, tzm-Latn-DZ, wo, wo-SN, x-IV_mathan, xh, xh-ZA, yo, yo-BJ, yo-NG, zu, zu-ZA
>
> #### Windows-1253 (Greek)
>
> el, el-CY, el-GR
>
> #### Windows-1254 (Turkish)
>
> az, az-Latn, az-Latn-AZ, tr, tr-CY, tr-TR, uz, uz-Latn, uz-Latn-UZ
>
> #### Windows-1255 (Hebrew)
>
> he, he-IL
>
> #### Windows-1256 (Arabic)
>
> ar, ar-*, fa, fa-IR, ku, ku-Arab, ku-Arab-IQ, pa-Arab, pa-Arab-PK, prs, prs-AF, sd, sd-Arab, sd-Arab-PK, tzm-Arab, tzm-Arab-MA, ug, ug-CN, ur, ur-IN, ur-PK
>
> #### Windows-1257 (Baltic)
>
> et, et-EE, lt, lt-LT, lv, lv-LV
>
> #### Windows 1258 (Vietnamese)
>
> vi, vi-VN
>
> #### CP874: ISO 8859-11 (Thai)
>
> th, th-TH
>
> #### CP932: Shift JIS (Japanese)
>
> ja, ja-JP, ja-JP_radstr
>
> #### CP936: GBK (Chinese)
>
> zh, zh-CN, zh-CN_phoneb, zh-CN_stroke, zh-Hans, zh-Hans-HK, zh-Hans-MO, zh-SG, zh-SG_phoneb, zh-SG_stroke
>
> #### CP949: Unified Hangul Code (Korean)
>
> ko, ko-KR
>
> #### CP950: Big5 (Chinese)
>
> zh-Hant, zh-HK, zh-HK_radstr, zh-MO, zh-MO_radstr, zh-MO_stroke, zh-TW, zh-TW_pronun, zh-TW_radstr

Answer (score 3):

You can enumerate all the locales (using EnumSystemLocales/EnumSystemLocalesEx), then get the ANSI code page (GetLocaleInfo/GetLocaleInfoEx with LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE).